# Neutron absorption cross-section of Boron-10

Tags: nuclear-physics

Cross-section of $^{10}$B monotonically decreases with neutron energy. But it does not have any resonance absorption peaks unlike in the cross-sections of $^{239}$Pu and $^{238}$U. Why?

Comment: There certainly is structure starting at around 0.5MeV. The 10B(n,g)11B cross section is pretty smooth. Have you looked at the data on ENDF?

Comment: The isobar diagrams at https://nucldata.tunl.duke.edu/ are also useful.

Answer (score 1):

The fission of $^{10}B$

$^{10}\mathrm{B} + ^{1}\mathrm{n} \longrightarrow ^7\mathrm{Li} + ^4\mathrm{He} +  \text{2.8 MeV} $

implies that there should be resonance somewhere for the reaction to occur.